# C# getting current time every second and performing some operation

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, timer

I have a `UserControl`. On Load event of this `UserControl`, i am creating a `timer` with an interval of 1 sec. In `Timer_tick` function i'm getting the `current Date` and then Iterating through a `LIST` that contains some other `UserControls`. And checking if the Current Date matches the Date stored in List then perform something. It works fine till here. But as soon as i get `Current time` and compare it with the time stored in LIST. it behaves weird. No 1 it never matches the time on Windows taskbar showing.(okey still fine). but when a condition fulfills, Time stored in LIST and Current time matches. It perform some function but then it just keeps performing it and even the current time is changed and condition is false still it keeps doing. What i am doing wrong ?

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
private async void TodoListControl_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // UserControl Load
{
timer.Interval = (1000);
timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
timer.Start();
}
```

**Timer_tick**

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string date = now.ToShortDateString();
 foreach (var item in result)
  {
    if(item.Date.Trim() == date.Trim() && item.Time.Trim() ==   now.ToString("t").Trim())
  {
    ParentWindow.SnackbarNotification.IsActive = false;
    ParentWindow.SnackbarNotification.Message.Content = $"{item.Title} - {item.Date} - {item.Time}";
    ParentWindow.SnackbarNotification.IsActive = true;
  }
  else
  { 
    ParentWindow.SnackbarNotification.IsActive = false;
  }
}   
}
```

Comment: DateTime includes a millisecond part. Your chances to match the millisecond part exactly is non-existant. Instead go for `>=` checks. With those you have a chance. Turning the whole thing into a string operation was propably a bad idea as well. Strings are among the lasts types you should ever try to work with.

Comment: Why are you converting the date to a string, and then comparing the strings? Dates are easily compared with the `>` and `==` type operators... Your timer ticks every 1 second, why not just assume that the time changes each timer tick and ignore all the date/time checks?

Comment: @Christopher i am getting only this thing like 12:30 PM when getting current time and comparing it with stored time exactly in same format. why when condition is false current time is changed 12:31 PM still it doesn't fall back and still keeps performing operation when condition was true ?

Comment: @RonBeyer because Date stored in Database is in string format ! :( i didn't get your second point !

Comment: and as i have mentioned problem is not with Date it's working fine when comparing dates problem is with time :(

Comment: 1. I would check if TodoListControl_OnLoaded is being called more then once from some reason. 2. How much time does it take to perform the Timer_Tick. See that not more then a second. Each one of those could be a reason for stacking calls to the method.

Comment: @RonBeyer Timer never ignore checks ! i have tested it does check each condition .

Comment: @Hammas_stack1, take into account that this method is being called every second in different threads. You probably are debugging a different thread and that's why you see inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: nothing is resolving the problem ! can someone please suggest me what to do . i am trying to get the current time and compare it with stored time and if matches show a notification !

Comment: Your code is a mess. The variable `string time` should be defined outside the loop. Or removed, because it is never used anywhere. You don't show how `now` is set. It is unclear which effect `ParentWindow.SnackbarNotification.IsActive = false` has, which is finally always called (except your comparison matches exactly the last item). What is all this supposed to do? Why don't you use a DispatcherTimer when you want to update the UI?

Comment: @Clemens hi sir ! sorry forgot to remove that string time. i was testing different things. now is set as global.`DateTime now = DateTime.Now;`. snackbar is just a notification popup that will alert. and i am trying to create a Todo. getting current time and comparing it with stored time. if matches showing notification !

Comment: @Clemens everything works fine if i only compare the current DATE with stored date. But when compare Current time that i get using `now.ToString("t")` with stored time in same format.

Comment: "*if matches showing notification*" and then? Continue the loop to set IsActive back to false in the next iteration? You probably want to leave the loop when a match is found?

Comment: @i want to leave the loop when match is again become false ! i mean current time is 12:30 and store time is 12:30 . Condition true and notification is shown until the current time is 12:30 because every time condition is true. but because time is running and when time becomes 12:31 the condition is false and it should stop showing notification as the notification shown case is now false ! but i keeps showing notification :(

Comment: Kindly help :( it's not solving :( idk what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the reason. If current time fetched using `now.ToString("t")` is 12:30 PM and it matches stored time 12:30 PM then the condition is true and notification is shown but then the condition `if(item.Date.Trim() == date.Trim() && item.Time.Trim() ==   now.ToString("t").Trim())` never becomes false. Because time that i get every second using this `now.ToString("t")` never updates.

i mean when first time i fetched `now.ToString("t")` in condition check it always remains the same as `12:30`. it never increases. And the reason of this was `now` was defined globally as `DateTime now = DateTime.Now;` so idk why but every time in a local scope i run `now.ToString("t")` i get same time that it gets on first run.

So i declared now locally in my function and every second this `DateTime now = DateTime.Now;` also runs before `now.ToString("t")` and i get the latest time